# update HTML dataTable from variable JSON file using datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I'm having an impossible time with my first website.

What I would like to happen, is when the user presses "go" on the datepicker, the dataTable will reload using a different data file that corresponds to that date..

Currently, my code does not do anything like this. It has a default data display, which is fine, and when i click go on the datepicker a new file loads in, but I cannot figure out how to make that file variable based on the datepicker date. Currently it is always the same file no matter what date is chosen.

What i have tried and failed with:

- xmlhttprequest to get the data (continuously getting CORS error, which I still don't understand despite reading about it online.)
- reading text file function and storing into jsonDataRatings (this makes jsonDataRatings a string which makes the rest of the script fail)
- overwriting the default data file (the examples i have tried all failed, nothing displays at all)

Thanks in advance for your help, I have been stuck here for 3 days without advancement.

*EDIT* - The json data is located on the server in the directory with the code (as is shown in the html code) so I don't understand why I get the CORS error with XMLHttpRequest

*EDIT #2* - The XMLHTTP code I used was this:

```
function loadJSON(callback) {
  var date = document.getElementById("standingsDate");
  var file = "data/NHL/DataForNHL_" + date.value + ".json";
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', file, true); 
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
    callback(xobj.responseText);
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);
}

function init() {
  loadJSON(function(response) {
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
    return actual_JSON;
  });
}
```

with this to call the function:

```
var jsonDataRatings = loadJSON();
```

and the json file is the same as posted below except is enclosed with

```
{
    "data": 
}
```

instead of

```
var jsonDataRatings =
```

This effort gives me this error despite having defined jsonDataRatings already:

```
jsonDataRatings is undefined
```

Here is the jsfiddle of current version (xmlhttprequest part removed):

https://jsfiddle.net/lewisMayonnaise/5fLtyx98/

And the data file format is this:

```
 var jsonDataRatings = [
        {
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1097.95,
            "League points": "TBD",
            "Team": {
                "Team": "St. Louis Blues",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/stLouisBlues.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Central",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD",
        },
        {
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 897.47,
            "League points": "TBD",
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Anaheim Ducks",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/anaheimDucks.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Pacific",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1040.08,
            "League points": "TBD",
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Minnesota Wild",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/minnesotaWild.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Central",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1000.21,
            "League points": "TBD",
             "Team": {
                "Team": "Calgary Flames",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/calgaryFlames.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"

            },
            "Division": "Pacific",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 700.0,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Detroit Red Wings",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/detroitredwings.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"

            },
            "Division": "Atlantic",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1038.53,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Columbus Blue Jackets",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/columbusBlueJackets.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"

            },
            "Division": "Metropolitan",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1021.95,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Nashville Predators",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/nashvillePredators.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Central",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 965.08,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Arizona Coyotes",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/arizonaCoyotes.jpg' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Pacific",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1027.39,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Toronto Maple Leafs",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/torontomapleleafs.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Atlantic",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1130.45,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Colorado Avalanche",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/coloradoAvalanche.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Central",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 885.77,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "San Jose Sharks",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/sanJoseSharks.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Pacific",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1029.81,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Florida Panthers",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/floridapanthers.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Atlantic",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1044.94,
            "League points": "TBD",
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Winnipeg Jets",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/winnipegJets.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>" 
            },
            "Division": "Central",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1030.67,            
            "League points": "TBD",
            "Team": {
                "Team": "New York Rangers",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/nyRangers.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Metropolitan",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1126.12,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Philadelphia Flyers",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/philedelphiaFlyers.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Metropolitan",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1118.57,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Tampa Bay Lightning",
                "modification": "+-diff",
            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/tampsbaylightning.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Atlantic",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1187.02,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Boston Bruins",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/bostonbruins.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Atlantic",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1004.08,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Dallas Stars",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/dallasStars.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Central",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 853.25,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Ottawa Senators",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/ottawasenators.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Atlantic",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1018.74,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Pittsburgh Penguins",
                "modification": "+-diff",
            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/pittsburghPenguins.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Metropolitan",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 894.43,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Buffalo Sabres",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/buffalo.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Atlantic",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1074.4,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Vegas Golden Knights",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/vegaGoldenKnights.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Pacific",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1052.8,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Washington Capitals",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/washingtonCapitals.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Metropolitan",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1015.36,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Carolina Hurricanes",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/carolinaHurricanes.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Metropolitan",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 967.36,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "New York Islanders",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/nyIslanders.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Metropolitan",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 936.82,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Los Angeles Kings",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/lakings.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"

            },
            "Division": "Pacific",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 954.39,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Chicago Blackhawks",
                "modification": "+-diff",
            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/chicagoBlackhawks.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Central",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
            
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 981.37,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "New Jersey Devils",
                "modification": "+-diff",
            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/njDevils.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Metropolitan",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 874.51,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Montreal Canadiens",
                "modification": "+-diff",
            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/montrealcanadiens.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Atlantic",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 981.42,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Vancouver Canucks",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/vancouverCanucks.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Pacific",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        },
        {
            
            "Date": "2020-03-11",
            "Rating": 1049.06,
            "League points": "TBD",
            
            "Team": {
                "Team": "Edmonton Oilers",
                "modification": "+-diff",
                            "Logo": "<img src='img/NHLpics/edmontonOilers.gif' style='height:40%; width:40%;'>"
            },
            "Division": "Pacific",
            "President's Trophy": "TBD",
            "Playoff Qualifier": "TBD",
            "Conference winner": "TBD",
            "Stanley Cup": "TBD"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Where are you getting the json data from? You have to make a request to fetch it, either with `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()`.  If you're encountering CORS errors, maybe you aren't allowed to access the API.

Comment: I was using XMLHttpRequest, and getting the cors error. the json data is a file on my local machine, so access shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet you used for the XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax turned out to be the most straightforward way to do this. Here is a snippet from the working code :

```
    var path = "data/NHL/DataForNHL_2021-05-19.json";
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        paging: false,
        destroy: true,
        "ajax": path,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Rating", 
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) { 
    //console.log( data )
    return data.Rating + ' ' + data.modification ;
  }},
            { "data": "League_points" },
            { "data": "Team",
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) { 
    //console.log( data )
    return data.Team + ' <br> ' + data.Logo ;
  }},
            { "data": "Division" },
            { "data": "President's Trophy" },
            { "data": "Playoff Qualifier" },
            { "data": "Conference Winner" },
            { "data": "Stanley Cup" }
        ]
    } );
    
} );
```